# cultureinfo for month and year only

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

I am getting date as string parameter that is **ExpDate** as **12/16**(month/year), i need to convert it as DateTime and save it to the sql db, i convert the above string to date as

```
paymentMethod.ExpirationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ExpDate);
```

this absolutely working in my machine and saved in my db. but this is throws an error in my colleague's machine as

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

i have googled it and i come to know that i need to do cultureinfo. but i am getting the date as MM/yy only that is why i cant go through it. can anyone tell what do i need to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this overload:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx

```
paymentMethod.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Parse(ExpDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: it's not working though, please consider my date string is month and year only like 12/16

Comment: This is what i required **paymentMethod.ExpirationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ExpDate, "MM/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);** thanks for the info...